# how to use tfa.seq2seq.dynamic_decode in tensorflow 2.0 at the time of inference

Tags: tensorflow2.0, seq2seq

In tensorflow 2.0, input tensors need to be fed at the time of calling and not at the time of constructing. I am trying to use dynamic_decode for a seq2seq task. How can i use dynamic_decode and get outputs with 1 line of code instead of handling initialize() and then step() manually for timesteps. In tf 1.14 you could pass initial_state tensors to constructor.

```
greedy_sampler = tfa.seq2seq.GreedyEmbeddingSampler()

decoder_input = tf.expand_dims([Y_tokenizer.word_index['<start>']]* inference_batch_size,1)
decoder_emb_inp = decoderNetwork.decoder_embedding(decoder_input)

decoder_instance = tfa.seq2seq.BasicDecoder(decoderNetwork.decoder_rnncell, greedy_sampler)

#initialize inference decoder

(first_finished, first_inputs,first_state) = decoder_instance.initialize(decoder_embedding_matrix,
                             start_tokens = start_tokens, end_token=end_token, initial_state = s_prev)


final_outputs, final_state, final_sequence_lengths = tfa.seq2seq.dynamic_decode(decoder_instance,
                                                                                maximum_iterations=maximum_iterations,
                                                                                )
```

I get below error when i try to use dynamic_decode. it cannot find initial_state tensor

```
     52 final_outputs, final_state, final_sequence_lengths = tfa.seq2seq.dynamic_decode(decoder_instance,
---> 53                                                                                 maximum_iterations=maximum_iterations,
     54                                                                                 )
     55 

1 frames

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow_addons/seq2seq/decoder.py in dynamic_decode(decoder, output_time_major, impute_finished, maximum_iterations, parallel_iterations, swap_memory, training, scope, **kwargs)
    333             decoder_init_kwargs = kwargs.pop("decoder_init_kwargs", {})
    334             initial_finished, initial_inputs, initial_state = \
--> 335                 decoder.initialize(decoder_init_input, **decoder_init_kwargs)
    336 
    337         zero_outputs = tf.nest.map_structure(

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow_addons/seq2seq/basic_decoder.py in initialize(self, inputs, initial_state, **kwargs)
     69         # Assume the dtype of the cell is the output_size structure
     70         # containing the input_state's first component's dtype.
---> 71         self._cell_dtype = tf.nest.flatten(initial_state)[0].dtype
     72         return self.sampler.initialize(inputs, **kwargs) + (initial_state,)
     73 

AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'dtype'
```

Answer (score 0):

I have faced the same error.
In my case,

```
final_outputs, final_state, final_sequence_lengths = tfa.seq2seq.dynamic_decode(
  decoder_instance,
  maximum_iterations=maximum_iterations,
  decoder_init_input=some_inputs,
  decoder_init_kwargs={"initial_state": some_initial_state)
```

can avoid the error.
This seems to be caused by [this line](https://github.com/tensorflow/addons/blob/v0.7.1/tensorflow_addons/seq2seq/decoder.py#L333).

Answer (score 0):

tfa.seq2seq.dynamic_decode() internally calls initialize() on BasicDecoder, which requires input and initial_state.
Thus you need to pass 'decoder_init_input' and 'decoder_init_kwargs' parameters to dynamic_decode()

```
tfa.seq2seq.dynamic_decode(decoder = decoder,
                            maximum_iterations = self.max_output_sequence_length,
                            swap_memory = True,
                            scope = decoder_scope,
                            decoder_init_input= decoder_embeddings_matrix,
                            decoder_init_kwargs= {
                                'initial_state' : decoder_initial_state,
                                'start_tokens': start_tokens, 'end_token': end_token
                            })
```